# S3 replacing default xml error with custom error not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I feel stupid for having to ask this but I cannot get amazon's s3 error document to work. What I want to do is show a custom error document when a user tries to access a file that doesn't not exist. So I followed to documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/CustomErrorDocSupport.html but this simply doesn't work.

I can access files that exist but when I enter https://mybucketurl/notexistingdoc.html it trows the usual access denied/key not found xml error.

As the documentation is pretty barebones and it there isn't much to configure I have no clue what is wrong. I even tried setting to permissions on my bucket to s3:* to make sure it wasn't a permission issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is tried and my error page also works.

- Created a bucket, changed permission to make it public.
- under permission -> block public access turn it off , and
  attached a policy bucket policy to grant public read access to  your bucket. When you grant public read access, anyone on the     internet   can access your bucket.

  ```
  {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": "*",
              "Action": "s3:GetObject",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket name/*"
          }
      ] }
  ```
- upload your index.html and error.html as objects
- my error.html file `<h1>there was an error</h1>`
- Go to properties, under static website hosting,enable it,choose a
  hosting type as static,  mention **exact names** index.html for index document and
  error.html for error document nd then you can verify it by trying to
  access your bucket URL with anything which doesn't exist it will
  render the error page

For detailed explanation follow [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html#step6-upload-error-doc)

Comment: That is what I did but it didn't work. I started again from scratch and now it does. I must have mistyped something even though I'm pretty sure I didn't as I could access all my files.

Comment: maybe you mistyped the name of the error file when mentioning it, which caused s3 to reader their default error page.